# Vaadin "A connector with id xy is already registered"

Tags: vaadin

Somewhere in my Vaadin application, I'm getting this exception as soon as I connect using a second browser

`Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: A connector with id 22 is already registered!
    at com.vaadin.ui.ConnectorTracker.registerConnector(ConnectorTracker.java:133)`

It happens always in the same place but I don't know why exactly as the reason for this must be somewhere else.

I think I might be stealing UI components from the other session - which is not my intention.
Currently, I don't see any `static` instances of UI components I might be using in multiple sessions.

How can I debug this? It's become quite a large project.
Any hints to look for?

Comment: Are you using spring to manage vaadin?

Comment: Watch [this](http://ttlnews.blogspot.nl/2013/07/vaadin-error-connector-with-id-7-is.html) maybe can help you

Comment: No I'm not using Spring

Comment: What do my components have to do with this connector? Is there any way you should/can register one yourself?

Comment: For posterity, here is similar thread (solved) in [Vaadin Forum](https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/4007130).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think I might be stealing UI components from the other session - which is not my intention. Currently, I don't see any static instances of UI components I might be using in multiple sessions.

That was it. I was actually stealing UI components without prior knowledge.

It was very well hidden in a part which seems to be same for all instances. Which is true: the algorithm is the same.

Doesn't mean I should've reused the same UI components as well...

Thanks to those who took a closer look.

Comment: Did you try the Jose Luis Martin solution for debugging this problem and finaly find a solution ?

Comment: No I didn't. I found it by looking again at my code - of which I thought it was "safe"

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this usually happens because you are attaching a component already attached in other session.

Try logging the failed connector with a temporal `ConnectorTracker`, So the next time that it happens, you can catch it.

For example:

```
public class SomeUI extends UI {

  private ConnectorTracker tracker;

  @Override
  public ConnectorTracker getConnectorTracker() {
    if (this.tracker == null) {
      this.tracker =  new ConnectorTracker(this) {

        @Override
        public void registerConnector(ClientConnector connector) {
          try {
            super.registerConnector(connector);
          } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            getLogger().log(Level.SEVERE, "Failed connector: {0}", connector.getClass().getSimpleName());
            throw e;
          }
        }

      };
    }

    return tracker;
  }
}
```

Comment: Definitely one for your own private knowledge base, thank you!

Comment: @jose-luis-martin Hi ! When I put this code in my UI class, I get a NullPointerException... Do you have any idea why ?

Comment: @Manu Oh! yes, I just edited to fix the code. Thanks.

Comment: @JoseLuisMartin Thanks for this fix. The `connector.getClass().getSimpleName()` give 'Failed connector: HorizontalSplitPanel'. I've got only one HorizontalSplitPanel in my code so it easy to find. The error is provided when I add it to an other component. So what do I have to do to avoid the error ?

Comment: Just ensure that you are not adding the same instance twice.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I fixed it -

1) look for components you have shared across sessions. For example if you have declared a component as static it will be created once and will be shared.

2) if you are not able to find it and want a work around until you figure out the real problem, put your all addComponent calls in try and in catch add following code -

```
getUI().getConnectorTracker().markAllConnectorsDirty();
getUI().getConnectorTracker().markAllClientSidesUnititialized();
getPage().reload():
```

This will clear old connectors and will reload the page properly only when it fails. For me it was failing when I was logged out and logged in back.

Once you find the real problem you can fix it till then inform your customers about the reload.

**** note - only solution is to remove shared components this is just a work around.

Answer (score 0):

By running your application in debug mode (add ?debug at the end of URL in browser) you will be able to browse to the component, e.g:

-UIConnector(0)
--VerticalLayoutConnector(1)
---...
---LabelConnector(22)

where 22 is id from your stack trace. Find this component in your code and make sure that it is not static (yes, I saw such examples).